# How to select value of all the tbody inputs values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, children

so I have some checkboxes, when each one is checked I'm able to get the id number I need from the associated table row and place them into my `contacts` array.

I also have a **Select all checkbox** which is meant to grab all the id numbers and stick them into the same array.

Having a bit of trouble trying to figure out the correct syntax to target the tbody, select every table row's data-id, or every table row's input's value.

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/7LCjH/

^ In my fiddle example you can see the numbers get added to my array (or the gray div for visualization).

---

How would you grab all the id numbers from the tbody rows from the Select all checkbox?

jQuery

```
var contacts = [];

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
    $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    //contacts.push($('#tbody').children(tr > td > input).val();)
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function() {

    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = $tr.data('coworker-id');

    contacts.push(id);

    $('#arrayContent').empty();
    $('#arrayContent').append(contacts+',');

    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }   

});
```

HTML

```
<table>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></td>
        <td>Select All</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="tbody">
    <tr data-coworker-id="1">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-coworker-id="2">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-coworker-id="3">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: I think I just figured it out! With `$('#tbody tr').each(function() {
        contacts.push($(this).data('coworker-id'));` going to do more testing and try it in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your select all handler like so:

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
    $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked).each(function() {
         contacts.push($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Woot! I think this is the simplest solution so far :)

Comment: Ok cool I choose this for the lease amount of code, and I could also easily reset my array before the big push

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
var contacts = [];

// add multiple select / deselect functionality

$("#selectall").click(function () {
    var els = $('.case')
    if (els.first().is(':checked') ) {
        els.prop('checked', false);
        $('#arrayContent').empty();
    } else {
        els.attr('checked', true);
        $.each(els, function(index, el) {
             contacts.push( $(el).val() ); 
        });
        $('#arrayContent').empty();
        $('#arrayContent').append(contacts.join( ', ' ) );
    }
    //contacts.push($('#tbody').children(tr > td > input).val();)
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa

$(".case").click(function() {

    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = $tr.data('coworker-id');

    contacts.push(id);

    $('#arrayContent').empty();
    $('#arrayContent').append(contacts+',');

    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }   

});
```

and here is fiddle link :: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/7LCjH/24/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! :D +1

Comment: no problem, glad to help, this can also be improved on too, it works but it could be a lot better, now that you see how it is working, try to improve it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {

if($('.case:checked').length == $('.case').length){
    //deselect all
    $('.case').removeAttr("checked");
    contacts = [];
}
else{
    //select all
    $('.case').attr("checked", "checked").each(function(){

        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = $tr.data('coworker-id');

        contacts.push(id);

    })
}    




$('#arrayContent').empty();
$('#arrayContent').append(contacts.join(','));
//contacts.push($('#tbody').children(tr > td > input).val();)
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LCjH/26/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead of `children` and then loop the elements to add them to the array.

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
  $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
  $('tbody').find("input").each(function () {
    contacts.push($(this).val()+",");
  });
  $('#arrayContent').append(contacts);
});
```

> The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't quite answer the question using children, but you can use `$('#tbody').find('input')` to find all the input fields within an element.